# String concatenation bug with long SQL Strings in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, string, concatenation

I have found a very strange behaviour in C# regarding String concatenation with SQL Statements.
I'm executing this method a few thousand times and the bug occurs very seldom and only when many line breaks are within the string. It seems to be independent of the length of the string.

Unfortunately I cannot post the full SQLs here as these are business secrets from my company.

Consider a generated SQL Insert Statement, which has a SQL-Select-Statement as one of it's values. All possible `"` within the Select-Statements are deleted before, so there is no error with closing the string.

```
string myString = "INSERT INTO ... (COLUMN_NAMES, SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT) 
                   VALUES (SOME_VALUES, '{VERY_LONG_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT}',1)"
```

The strange thing that happens is that myString contains everything till `VERY_LONG_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT`. The last part of the string `"}',1)"` is not within the string. When I make a break point and do it within the code window, the bug doesn't occur and the string is complete.

Any suggestions? In my opinion this is clearly a bug within C#. Has anybody had a similar problem?

Comment: "In my opinion this is clearly a bug within C#." -  no, I don't think it is (unless it is more than 2 GB in length, but that would be silly...)

Comment: Strings have a max length... surely you're not hitting `int.MaxValue`? There is no bug in the use of strings.. if there was  I would be amazed. We concatenate gigantic strings in our codebase too (not SQL).. so you can be sure it is well tested

Comment: are you using `DbParameter` from ado.net? With parameters, you could specify your database type and avoid the string problems with sql. (as `'` or `"` chars).

Comment: this sounds like you are not escaping your characters correctly. Maybe you are adding " instead of \"

Comment: I'm getting the VERY_LONG_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT- String from a OracleDataReader by executing "SELECT sql_text from dba_hist_sqltext WHERE ...". I've figured out that it seems to work, when cutting of the last character from it with selectstring = selectstring.substring(0,selectstring.Length-1). That works for me, but I think it is still strange. Maybe the OracleDataReader sends a invisible-String-End-sign, which is interpreted by C#?

Comment: @user2372727 That wouldn't explain the *"occurs very seldom"* part.

Answer (score 0):

By default you need to concatenate your string across line breaks.  Alternatively you can use the @ symbol like so:

var myString = @"INSERT INTO ... (COLUMN_NAMES, SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT) 
                   VALUES (SOME_VALUES, '{VERY_LONG_SQL_SELECT_STATEMENT}',1)"